# Meteor: Can't display my collections

Tags: mongodb, meteor, collections

I have a collection named by "btso". I just tried to display this collection from this database but it doesn't display. I don't know if i have any errors in my code.

Here is main.html

```html
<head>
  <title>Sanji</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h4>Sanji's first meteor app</h4>
    <ul class="collection">
        {{> sanji}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

<template name="sanji">
  {{#each btso}}
    <li class="collection-item">{{text}}</li>a
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Here is my main lib/collections.js

```js
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

export const Btso = new Mongo.Collection('btso');
```

And here is my main.js

```js
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';

import { Btso } from '../lib/collections.js';

import './main.html';

Template.sanji.helpers({
  btso: function(){
    return  Btso.find({});
  }
});
```

Comment: do you have any errors showing in terminal or browser console ?

Comment: do you load your collection on the server ? you have to add import '../lib/collections.js'; (with proper location according to your structure) in server/main.js

Comment: also do your btso have a text attribute ?

Comment: Please add your publication and check if it has been imported in your server main file.

Comment: @lvo there are no any errors showing on both consoles. Also i have two attributes on my "btso" collection. I checked it by using db.btso.find({}); on my terminal console.

Comment: did you import the file on the server side as mentioned in my second comment and in Jankapunkt's comment ?